# Removing square brackets from panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I have a dataframe that I need to remove the square brackets from in order to input into a loop.

I've tried using str.strip and str.commands. However I get errors saying I must pass a dataframe with boolean values. It seems the values in my data frame are lists.

```
m2 = pd.read_csv('newm2.csv', sep=',s', header=None)
print m2
```

Sample input:

```py
m2 = pd.DataFrame([
    [[14,38,51,65,84,85]],
    [[3,34,58,65,66,75]],
    [[3,15,68,70,80,82]],
    [[19,31,42,50,54,97]],
    [[4,9,48,62,74,77]],
])
```

```
                         0
0      [14,38,51,65,84,85]
1       [3,34,58,65,66,75]
2       [3,15,68,70,80,82]
3      [19,31,42,50,54,97]
4        [4,9,48,62,74,77]
```

Above is a small example of what it's currently printing. I need each row to look like:

```
"14,38,51,65,84,85"
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: df[0].apply(','.join)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way is to transform the `list` into  a `str`:

```py
x = [
    [[14,38,51,65,84,85]],
    [[3,34,58,65,66,75]],
    [[3,15,68,70,80,82]],
    [[19,31,42,50,54,97]],
    [[4,9,48,62,74,77]],
]

m2 = pd.DataFrame(x)
m2[0] = m2[0].apply(lambda x: ','.join([str(i) for i in x]))

m2
Out[1]:
        0
0      '14,38,51,65,84,85'
1      '3,34,58,65,66,75'
2      '3,15,68,70,80,82'
3      '19,31,42,50,54,97'
4       '4,9,48,62,74,77'
```

**Edit**

What if the rows are of type `str` and not actually `list`. We just convert them to be understood as literal str and then perform the `.join`

```py
from ast import literal_eval

x = [
    ['[14,38,51,65,84,85]'],
    ['[3,34,58,65,66,75]'],
    ['[3,15,68,70,80,82]'],
    ['[19,31,42,50,54,97]'],
    ['[4,9,48,62,74,77]'],
]

m2 = pd.DataFrame(x)

m2[0] = m2[0].apply(lambda x: ','.join([str(i) for i in literal_eval(x)]))
m2
Out[1]:
        0
0      '14,38,51,65,84,85'
1      '3,34,58,65,66,75'
2      '3,15,68,70,80,82'
3      '19,31,42,50,54,97'
4       '4,9,48,62,74,77'
```

Comment: Thank you for this. However the output is now: 0       [,1,4,,,3,8,,,5,1,,,6,5,,,8,4,,,8,5,]

Comment: It should only be that if you run it twice on the dataset. If you load and run the function, it should return the string. It is the same idea provided by @WeNYoBen (his is more concise and to the point)

Comment: As far as I can tell I'm only running it once, could there be something causing it to run twice?

Comment: I think i know what is happening. Your info is probably as string. Let me update my answer

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid `apply` due to its inferior performance. Here's another way.

```
m2 = pd.DataFrame([
    [[14,38,51,65,84,85]],
    [[3,34,58,65,66,75]],
    [[3,15,68,70,80,82]],
    [[19,31,42,50,54,97]],
    [[4,9,48,62,74,77]],
])
m2.iloc[:, 0] = m2.iloc[:, 0].astype(str)
m2.iloc[:, 0] = ['"' + x.strip('[').strip(']').replace(' ','') + '"' for x in m2.iloc[:, 0]]
m2
```

The output:

```
                0
0   "14,38,51,65,84,85"
1   "3,34,58,65,66,75"
2   "3,15,68,70,80,82"
3   "19,31,42,50,54,97"
4   "4,9,48,62,74,77"
```

Answer (score 0):

As

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
```

you can

```
b = str(a) # out: '[1,2,3,4]'
```

to avoid '[' and ']'

```
b = str(a)[1:-1] # out: '1,2,3,4'
```

so, we just have to apply this to every array in the array m2[0]

```
import pandas as pd

m2 = pd.DataFrame([
    [[14,38,51,65,84,85]],
    [[3,34,58,65,66,75]],
    [[3,15,68,70,80,82]],
    [[19,31,42,50,54,97]],
    [[4,9,48,62,74,77]],
])

m2[0] = m2[0].apply(lambda x: str(x)[1:-1])

print(m2[0])
```

output:

```
0    14, 38, 51, 65, 84, 85
1     3, 34, 58, 65, 66, 75
2     3, 15, 68, 70, 80, 82
3    19, 31, 42, 50, 54, 97
4      4, 9, 48, 62, 74, 77
```