# How to remove square brackets and commas from dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, replace, series, brackets

I have column \df['R1'] in my dataframe and it looks like below;

```
    i1  i2       R1             R2                D
1   1.0 1.0 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0] [0.0, 0.0, 0.802]   -0.013347
2   1.0 1.0 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0] [0.0, 0.0, -0.802]  -0.013347
```

I desire to remove square brackets and commas.My initial approach  looks like below, but it does not work at the moment and I get same output with square brackets.

```
df['R1'].replace('[','').replace(']','').replace(',','')
```

I have checked a few links e.g. [Removing square brackets from panda dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57386372/removing-square-brackets-from-panda-dataframe), but would like to use pandas commands to solve my problem. Thanks for your kind suggestions

Comment: If it looks like that, it can one of two scenarios.  #1 Those are strings `"[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]"` OR  #2 those are lists `[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]`.  The answer depends on which it is.  Also, it depens on what you want in the end.  You haven't specified what you expect your final dataframe to be or look like.

Comment: @Ben.T R1 and R2 and numpy ndarrays. I would like to see the output like you can see in the answer of Yo_Chris. My problem is solved with this [str.replace]. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert to string and use `str.repalce` with `regex`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'i1': [1.0]*2, 'i2': [1.0]*2,
                   'R1': [[0.0]*3]*2, 'R2': [[0.0, 0.0, 0.802],[0.0, 0.0, -0.802]],
                   'D': [-0.013347]*2})

df['R1'] = df['R1'].astype(str).str.replace(r'\[|\]|,', '')
df['R2'] = df['R2'].astype(str).str.replace(r'\[|\]|,', '')

    i1   i2           R1              R2         D
0  1.0  1.0  0.0 0.0 0.0   0.0 0.0 0.802 -0.013347
1  1.0  1.0  0.0 0.0 0.0  0.0 0.0 -0.802 -0.013347
```